How do I organize two grids to be the same size as the smaller one using UIKit?
I'm trying to create an admin interface for a website, and I'm using UIKIT to make the job easier, however, I can't get this alignment:
enter image description here
I'm trying to make it so that when the table is bigger than the 3 cards on the side, it has a hidden overflow, so I don't have to scroll down, can anyone help me with this error?
code:
        <!-- opções da tabela -->
        
            <div class="uk-width-1-1" uk-grid uk-height-match="target: > div > uk-width-1-1">

                <div class="uk-width-2-3">
                    <div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-height-1-1">
                        <h1>Clientes</h1>
                        <div class="uk-card-header uk-hidden@s" style="padding-block: 0px; margin-block: 0px;">
                            <h2 class="uk-card-title">Clientes</h2>
                            <div class="uk-card-header uk-flex uk-flex-between uk-text-center uk-padding-small">
                                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-remove uk-button-small uk-width-1-1">Todo periodo</button>
                                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-remove uk-button-small uk-width-1-1">Ultima semana</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="uk-card-header uk-flex uk-flex-between uk-text-center">
                                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-remove uk-button-small uk-width-1-1">Ultimo mês</button>
                                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-remove uk-button-small uk-width-1-1">Ultimo ano</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="uk-card-header uk-visible@s" style="padding-block: 0px; margin-block: 0px;">
                            <div class="uk-card-header uk-flex uk-flex-between uk-text-center" style="padding-block: 0px; margin-block: 0px;">
                                <h2 class="uk-card-title uk-margin-remove">Clientes</h2>
                                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-remove uk-button-small">Todo periodo</button>
                                    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-remove uk-button-small">Ultima semana</button>
                                        <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-remove uk-button-small">Ultimo mês</button>
                                        <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-remove uk-button-small">Ultimo ano</button>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Tabela -->
                            <div class="uk-card-body uk-margin-small uk-padding-small uk-overflow-auto uk-height-1-1">
                                <table class="uk-table uk-table-striped uk-margin-remove">
                                    <caption></caption>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="uk-text-center">Nome</th>
                                            <th class="uk-text-center">Cidade</th>
                                            <th class="uk-text-center">Bairro</th>
                                            <th class="uk-text-center">Rua</th>
                                            <th class="uk-text-center">Numero</th>
                                            <th class="uk-text-center">Contato</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Maria</td>
                                            <td>Itu</td>
                                            <td>Santa Rita</td>
                                            <td>salvador</td>
                                            <td>12</td>
                                            <td>00-0000-0000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Maria</td>
                                            <td>Itu</td>
                                            <td>Santa Rita</td>
                                            <td>salvador</td>
                                            <td>12</td>
                                            <td>00-0000-0000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Maria</td>
                                            <td>Itu</td>
                                            <td>Santa Rita</td>
                                            <td>salvador</td>
                                            <td>12</td>
                                            <td>00-0000-0000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Maria</td>
                                            <td>Itu</td>
                                            <td>Santa Rita</td>
                                            <td>salvador</td>
                                            <td>12</td>
                                            <td>00-0000-0000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Maria</td>
                                            <td>Itu</td>
                                            <td>Santa Rita</td>
                                            <td>salvador</td>
                                            <td>12</td>
                                            <td>00-0000-0000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Maria</td>
                                            <td>Itu</td>
                                            <td>Santa Rita</td>
                                            <td>salvador</td>
                                            <td>12</td>
                                            <td>00-0000-0000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Maria</td>
                                            <td>Itu</td>
                                            <td>Santa Rita</td>
                                            <td>salvador</td>
                                            <td>12</td>
                                            <td>00-0000-0000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="uk-width-1-3">
                    <div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-height-1-1">
                            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-primary uk-margin-auto">
                                <h3 class="uk-card-title">Total de clientes</h3>
                                <h2 class="uk-margin-small">12</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-primary uk-margin-auto">
                                <h3 class="uk-card-title">Registrados esse mês</h3>
                                <h2 class="uk-margin-small">12</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-primary uk-margin-auto">
                                <h3 class="uk-card-title">Cidade com mais clientes</h3>
                                <h2 class="uk-margin-small">12</h2>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

I've tried using uk-height-match and uk-height-1-1 but nothing works

You can set the fixed height of the table container with overflow-y property.
